# Can I get and use the contact picture in my app?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I'm using the address book framework to get all the contacts from my iphone phonebook.

Is there any way to get (and use) the contact picture?

Thank you.

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to check out the Address Book documentation for iOS and especially look at the ABPerson reference.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210

Comment: thank you, unfortunately I don't really understand that documentation... :/ I have been there, I can get everything else from the contacts. :)

Comment: found the ABPersonCopyImageData() function :) Seems to work if you map it to (NSData *) and use imageWithData: thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can... this code from the Address Book API

```
array = [peoplePicker selectedRecords]; 
NSAssert([array count] == 1, @"Picker returned multiple selected records"); 

ABPerson *person = [array objectAtIndex:0];
personImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[person imageData]]; 
personFirstName = [person valueForProperty:kABFirstNameProperty], personLastName = [person valueForProperty:kABLastNameProperty];
/* ...do something with the image and name... */ [personImage release];
```

Comment: Is ABPerson available as an Objective-C class on iOS?  I thought it was just on the Mac.

Comment: I do remember I used it.. Not positive ... I think have sample code.. I will try to post once I get home.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a nice article](http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/421) how to pull pictures depending on the iOS version (pre 4.1 and currently preferred method)