# How to copy address book image and display it in table view?

Tags: iphone, image, nsdata, addressbook

How to copy images of all address book contacts onto an array, and later display it in Table view?

Comment: This SO question has your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874595/can-i-get-and-use-the-contact-picture-in-my-app

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any code samples for you, but I have APIs that you should call.

You need to delve into the AddressBook docs.

ABAddressBookGetPersonCount - gets the amount of persons in an ABAddressBookRef
ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople - gets an array of all the people in the book.
ABPersonCopyImageData and ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat will get you each person's image.

There are plenty of well defined examples of how to show images in a table, probably right on this website. Look into playing with UTableView, UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource.

Hope this helps!